# Quantile plot in GNU Octave 4.4.1

Tags: plot, octave, quantile

How to draw Quantile plot in GNU Octave 4.4.1? qqplot is not working in 4.4.1. I think it was supported before 4.2.1. For further investigation, https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Statistical-Plots.html

Now I can't use qqplot(x).

Comment: Why can't you use it? you get an error?

Comment: error: 'qqplot' undefined near line 13 column 1

Comment: You really should learn to have a quick look into the documentation. The NEWS explains which functions were moved to the statistics package, in your case qqplot. So you have to load(perhaps after installing) the octave force statistics package

Comment: As I am novice, I didn't know about about packages. Thanks a lot.